# Robotium case-insensitive search

Tags: android, regex, robotium

With Robotium, I have the following method:

```
solo.clickOnMenuItem("Foo");
```

Which effectively clicks a menu item with the "Foo" string in it. With Lollipop (and above), the text style for menus is `textAllCaps`, so the string search fails (shows "FOO" instead of "Foo").

Given that [Robotium supports regexes as arguments](http://robotium.googlecode.com/svn/doc/com/robotium/solo/Solo.html#clickOnMenuItem(java.lang.String,%20boolean)), I tried specifying the [case-insensitive embedded flag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) as a pattern:

```
solo.clickOnMenuItem("(?i)Foo");
```

But it fails to search the "FOO" menu item. How can I accomplish case-insensitive searching for menu items (and others view elements in general)?

Comment: @stribizhev yes, I tried that but it didn't work (it is in the question)

Comment: @stribizhev good catch! It was a question typo though, my code uses (?i). Edited question, thanks.

Comment: Try `[fF][oO][oO]`. Perhaps, flags are not supported.

Comment: Good idea, but doesn't work either